# Prolog rule for finding the last element of a list

Tags: prolog

i should write a rule on prolog, which finds the last element of a list and add 1 to it. Here's what i came up with so far. It works, but my question is can this rule be written otherwise:

```
element(D ,[_|B]):- element(D, B).
element(D, [X]):- D is X+1.
```

Comment: Why do you want to make it differently if it is working?

Answer (score 1):

(1) I'd rename the predicate to something like `last_element_incremented` which would be more descriptive than just `element` which doesn't say much.

(2) To make the rules non-overlapping, change the recursive rule:

```
last_element_incremented(Xinc, [_,X|T]) :- last_element_incremented(Xinc, [X|T]).
```

(3) If you use CLP(FD) you can make the solution more general. Also, swap the order of clauses so that you don't get a non-termination issue for more general queries:

```
last_element_incremented(Xinc, [X]) :- Xinc #= X + 1.
last_element_incremented(Xinc, [_,X|T]) :- last_element_incremented(D, [X|T]).
```

Then you can query, for example:

```
| ?- last_element_incremented(3, L).

L = [2] ? ;

L = [_,2] ? ;

L = [_,_,2] ? ;

L = [_,_,_,2] ? ;
```

(4) Finally, you could just use `append/3`:

```
last_element_incremented(Xinc, L) :- append(_, [X], L), Xinc #= X + 1.
```